# Expo - Package 'com.xxx.native.xxx' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'native' is a Java keyword

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, expo

I have used the pattern 'com.mycompanyname.native.appname' to name the bundle Ids for my apps since years and have created many apps using the keyword "native" in the package name. I didn't get this error when using classic expo builds until I switched to EAS builds.
Now, I have to upgrade a few of the live apps, can there be a workaround to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a workaround, which is a two step progress:

- Adjust the package name in your config to be a *valid* Java name
- Use a config plugin to set the applicationId in your build.gradle to your old package name

That way, your applicationId for Play Console stays the same, and the package name used in Java is valid for building.

Here is a gist with an example config plugin, and how to add it to your app.json:

https://gist.github.com/kbrandwijk/cef9e3b01cff91f8dfad8f47f02cb880